# Añadir opción de subtítulos a un vídeo en HTML

Tags: html, video

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Tarea 5</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video src="video.mp4" poster="imagen.png" controls=""></video>
</body>
</html>
```

Buenas una vez más a tod@s,

Tengo que insertar un vídeo en una web, pero no sé cómo indicar en los controles que el subtítulo sea opcional. ¿Hay alguna manera sólo usando HTML?

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Necesitas mostrar que tienes para saber como se muestra tu video.

Comment: Listo ;) Gracias por el apunte

Comment: Quizás esto te sea de ayuda https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video